# Rename: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] - working with rasters

Tags: python, replace, rename

In my code in Python I keep getting the error

*FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Z_Cawc_000_005_estimated_value.tfw' -> 'awc_000_005_estimated_value.tfw'*

So, 
'Z_Cawc_000_005_estimated_value.tfw' is the name of the first raster on a folder with 800 rasters.

All I want is to get rid off the initial "Z_C" characters of the 800 raster files in a folder.

My code is

```
    import os
    path = os.getcwd()
    filenames = 
    os.listdir(r'I:\PhD_2019\Spatial_Datasets\Baroon_Pocket_Dam_Catchment\Raster\Soil_Zonal_Stats')
    for filename in filenames:
        os.rename(filename, filename.replace("Z_C",""))
```

I`ve also try the following code:

```
    from os import rename, listdir

    badprefix = "Z_C"
    fnames = listdir('I:\\PhD_2019\\Spatial_Datasets\\Baroon_Pocket_Dam_Catchment\\Raster\\Soil_Zonal_Stats')

    for fname in fnames:
        if fname.startswith(badprefix):
            rename(fname, fname.replace(badprefix, '', 1))
```

and the following code as well:

```
    import os
    path =  os.getcwd()
    filenames = os.listdir(r'I:\PhD_2019\Spatial_Datasets\Baroon_Pocket_Dam_Catchment\Raster\Soil_Zonal_Stats' )

    for filename in filenames:
        os.rename(filename, filename.replace("Z_C", ""))
```

But both of them resulted in the same error! 
Can anyone let me know what is wrong with my code, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the full path to the file, otherwise python would look in your working directory and won't find the file. the fix is:

```
folder = r'I:\PhD_2019\Spatial_Datasets\Baroon_Pocket_Dam_Catchment\Raster\Soil_Zonal_Stats'
filenames = 
    os.listdir(r'I:\PhD_2019\Spatial_Datasets\Baroon_Pocket_Dam_Catchment\Raster\Soil_Zonal_Stats')
    for filename in filenames:
        os.rename(os.path.join(folder, filename), os.path.join(folder, filename.replace("Z_C","")))
```